# Q2 2020 Moderator Election — Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

As people may have noted, we've been short of moderator cover on this site for the past few months. Thanks to the Stack Exchange staff who have covered some of the workload in the meantime.

The significant change since moderators were last appointed in this community is that we've "graduated", which means that moderators are elected rather than appointed by Stack Exchange. As such, Stack Exchange are looking at scheduling an election; I've titled this post "Q2 2020" but that's indicative rather than anything else - the exact timing will depend on the workload of the appropriate Stack Exchange staff. To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. Like I mentioned, we're looking at scheduling the nomination period to start some time in Q2 2020.

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 10):

I have no interest in moderating or contributing, but I want to provide closure for [those who have asked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52809341#52809341).

I'm a former moderator formerly known as ᴍᴀsᴛᴇʀᴍɪɴᴅ_ᴇᴅ. I moderated Sports SE from 2012-2017, filling in for a user who felt the vision of the site was deviating from the original intent, if I recall correctly.

I wish I had more of a story as to why I left, but all I have is that my personal commitments were changing and my participation on the site was dwindling. Therefore, I thought it was time to move on. Also, since I no longer had interest in contributing to the site or the network, I requested my account to be deleted. The [information on my profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38521288#38521288) was following protocol to have my account deleted.

Since then, any interest I have had to return to contributing to the site and network has been tepid, at best. Therefore, I don't claim to have made [anonymous edits](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52831710#52831710), but I will claim 
to have provided intermittent answers. That said, how I currently feel about contributing to the site and network at the writing of this post is how I felt in 2017 when I stepped down as moderator.

To close, thank you for the memories. I do appreciate being asked about some 2.5 years later. I feel this closure will definitively close my involvement on this site and network while addressing users questions about why I left. I hope those who are selected as moderators continue their great work or have the opportunity to contribute great work as newly-appointed moderators.

Comment: Thank you for everything you did moderating the site, your dedication was much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

While I have been absent from both Sports and the network more widely for the past few months, I'm now upping my activity again so would be interested in standing.

Answer (score 3):

I have been hesitant to consider a moderator role previously, had an election been announced. However my concerns on the side of holding the role are now reduced or outweighed by wider considerations. I would nominate myself, and accept the support or otherwise of the community as indicated through an election.

Comment: I would personally welcome you as a moderator. Not that I get any more say than any other user in an election of course :-)

Comment: @Nij I would also prefer you as a moderator. You have my support.

Comment: @Nij I've been absent on the site for the last year but I would also support your candidacy.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it. I already tried it once on Gaming SE and I'm still up for it.

Comment: Well if we don't get too many moderators outside football, at least, if elected, one of them will be a goalie :D